# Emacs wrongly indent else expression in Python code

Tags: indentation, python

Say, I got a simple Python code snippet:

```
def demo(i):
    if(i):
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

I make indent-region for the whole buffer after save using `before-save-hook` in my `init.el`, so after `C-x C-s` in this buffer, it whole buffer will be automatically indented, this works for C and elisp source code perfectly, but in Python code, that code snippet will become:

```
def demo(i):
    if(i):
        print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

1. If I put point in `else` line, and type `TAB`, this line will be indented as it should be as the first code example.
2. If I mark the region of demo function or the whole buffer then type `TAB` or C-M-\ which is `indent-region`, the `else` line  will become the incorrect indention style.
3. If I `C-x C-s` to save this buffer which will also execute the `indent-region` for the whole buffer as I said early, the `else` line will become the incorrect indention style as the later code example.

According to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611681/emacs-python-indentation-for-single-line-if-else which was posted a year ago, the problem is not solved yet, so I post it here again to hope someone see it and give some solution.

**BTW**:

- GNU Emacs 24.4.1
- built-in python.el
- Fedora 21 32-bit

Comment: Perhaps you can accept the answer below if it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 6):

This is just a bug.  It's fixed in Emacs trunk.  Maybe you can grab a newer version of the mode from there, or dig the bug fix out of the git history.

Comment: Generally for these types of answers, I like to proactive and point to the commit to fix it -- partly as 'proof' and partly as 'this is the fix'. That's just my practice, but I think it would be helpful here :)